# How to know if a process is working correctly?

Tags: c, concurrency, fork, parent-child, child-process

The aim is to create a program that uses 10 processes (the original and 9 child processes) to concurrently write an “output.txt” file.
The idea is that each process writes a character string with a decimal number repeated 5 times. So the initial process will write 5 zeros (“00000”), the first child process 5 ones (“11111”), the second 5 doses (“22222”) and so on.
So the content of the file at the end will be: 0000011111222223333444445555566666777778888899999.

But i went to check if the program worked correctly executing the program 10 times in a row but the results were not the ones that i was expecting, because the program did not print some numbers in different executions.

This is my code.

numbers.c

```
int main(void)
{
    int fd1,fd2,i,pos;
    char c;
    char buffer[6];

    fd1 = open("output.txt", O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    write(fd1, "00000", 5);
    for (i=1; i < 10; i++) {
        pos = lseek(fd1, 0, SEEK_CUR);
        if (fork() == 0) {
            /* Child */
            sprintf(buffer, "%d", i*11111);
            lseek(fd1, pos, SEEK_SET);
            write(fd1, buffer, 5);
            close(fd1);
            exit(0);
        } else {
            /* Parent */
            lseek(fd1, 5, SEEK_CUR);
        }
    }

    //wait for all childs to finish
    while (wait(NULL) != -1);

    lseek(fd1, 0, SEEK_SET);
    printf("File contents are:\n");
    while (read(fd1, &c, 1) > 0)
        printf("%c", (char) c);
    printf("\n");
    close(fd1);
    exit(0);
}
```

Then i went to check if the program worked correctly executing the program 10 times in a row but these were the results.

```
$ for i in $(seq 10); do ./numbers ; done
File contents are:
0000011111222223333355555666668888899999
File contents are:
00000111112222255555666668888899999
File contents are:
0000011111222223333355555666668888899999
File contents are:
00000111112222244444666667777799999
File contents are:
00000444447777755555666668888899999
File contents are:
00000222224444455555777778888899999
File contents are:
0000011111222224444455555777778888899999
File contents are:
0000011111222225555544444888887777799999
File contents are:
0000011111222224444455555777778888899999
File contents are:
0000011111222225555544444888887777799999
```

I think some processes are not working correctly, so what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Unless you implement some kind of coordination among the processes, they can run in any order, so the output won't be sequential.

Comment: You're running into erratic scheduling and some dubious assumptions.  You should probably calculate the position where process `i` should write and do a positioned write ([`pwrite()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pwrite.html)) to that position.  The processes all share the open file description (which is a separate structure hidden behind the open file descriptors), so when a child moves the write position, it affects all the processes.  The `pwrite()` function doesn't move things and guarantees atomicity.

Answer (score 0):

As I noted in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74226978/how-to-know-if-a-process-is-working-correctly#comment131049972_74226978):

> You're running into erratic scheduling and some dubious assumptions. You should probably calculate the position where process `i` should write and do a positioned write (using [`pwrite()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pwrite.html)) to that position.
>
> The processes all share one [open file description](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) (which is a separate structure hidden behind the open file descriptors), so when a child moves the write position by using `write()` or `lseek()`, it affects all the processes. The `pwrite()` function doesn't move the current file position and guarantees atomic writes.

Your code could become:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char filename[] = "output.txt";
    char buffer[6];
    int fd1 = open(filename, O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    if (fd1 < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to open/create file '%s'\n", filename);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    write(fd1, "00000", 5);
    for (int i=1; i < 10; i++) {
        int offset = 5 * i;
        if (fork() == 0) {
            /* Child */
            sprintf(buffer, "%d", i*11111);
            pwrite(fd1, buffer, 5, offset);
            close(fd1);
            exit(0);
        }
    }

    while (wait(NULL) != -1)
        ;

    lseek(fd1, 0, SEEK_SET);
    printf("File contents are:\n");
    while (read(fd1, buffer, 5) > 0)
        printf("%.*s", 5, buffer);
    printf("\n");
    close(fd1);
    exit(0);
}
```

The output is predictable and boring:

```
File contents are:
00000111112222233333444445555566666777778888899999
```

You could get more interesting results if one or more of the children failed to do the writing; then there'd be null bytes in the file in place of the digits that should have been written (except for the last process).

If, for some unstated reason, you are not allowed to use `pwrite()`, then life is a lot harder.  You should eliminate the extraneous `lseek()` operations in the parent.  You can make the code close to deterministic by using [`nanosleep()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/nanosleep.html) and having each child sleep for `i` milliseconds before it seeks and writes.  Or you could use a formal synchronization mechanism of some sort — a semaphore, or a `pthread_mutex_t` ([`pthread_init()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_init.html)) mutex with the 'process shared' attribute set ([`pthread_mutexattr_setpshared()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutexattr_setpshared.html)).  If those aren't allowed either and the timing trick isn't acceptable, then you are definitely up against a wall.  It can be done, but there comes a point at which the prohibitions are pointless.